# Error in fitdist(): the dnormal function must be defined

Tags: r

I am having difficulty with fitting a distribution to my sample data using `fitdist`.

Here is the code:

```
fittrial <<- dnorm(severity,mean(severity),var(severity))
fitdist(fittrial,"normal")
```

I receive this error:

> Error in fitdist(fittrial, "normal") : 
>         The  dnormal  function must be defined

I have looked online and have tried everything I could understand how to do. I would really appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: Is it really `fitdist` or `fitdistr` you're using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is a confusion between two similarly named functions in different packages: `MASS::fitdistr()` (for which specifying "normal" for the `densfun` argument works) and `fitdistrplus::fitdist()` (for which it doesn't). See @Rakurai's answer for details on how to use `fitdistrplus::fitdist()`; this answer focuses on `MASS::fitdistr()`.

In addition:

- `dnorm()` takes mean and standard deviation, not mean and variance, as parameters.
- don't use the `<<-` assignment operator if you can avoid it.

```
severity <- 1:10
set.seed(101)  ## for reproducibility
fittrial <- rnorm(length(severity),mean(severity),sd(severity))

library("MASS")
```

Fit simulated Normal deviates:

```
fitdistr(fittrial,"normal")
##      mean         sd    
##   6.2418957   1.6785684 
##  (0.5308099) (0.3753393)
```

Fit original data:

```
fitdistr(severity,"normal")
##      mean         sd    
##   5.5000000   2.8722813 
##  (0.9082951) (0.6422616)
```

Comment: if it solved your problem, you are encouraged to click on the check-mark to accept the answer ...

Comment: Sorry about that. Thank you, its the first time I have used this forum. I appreciate your help

Comment: This doesn't explain how to use `fitdist`, it just asks OP to use `fitdistr` instead.  The problem was incorrect usage of `fitdist`.

Comment: that's fine, but it would be helpful to add (in your also-useful answer) that `fitdist` is in the `fitdistrplus` package (or wherever else you got it from?) At the time (3 years ago!) I was confused. (But note that my solution did help the OP ...)

Comment: Good, I think between us we have both packages covered.  I was confused by this an hour ago trying to use the "lognormal" distribution, and this seemed to be the only SO question with the error message.

Answer (score 6):

This answer relates to using `fitdist` from the `fitdistrplus` package, to which there are useful alternatives such as `fitdistr` from the `MASS` package.  From [the documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/fitdistrplus/versions/1.0-8/topics/fitdist) on the `fitdist` parameter `distr`:

> A character string "name" naming a distribution for which the
>   corresponding density function `dname`, the corresponding distribution
>   function `pname` and the corresponding quantile function `qname` must
>   be defined, or directly the density function.

The reason for the error message is that the distribution named "normal" is not defined in the R stats package.  There is no function named `dnormal`, hence the error message.

However, there is a distribution named "norm", and the correct solution is to change "normal" to "norm" which maps to the R stats function `dnorm`.

```
> fitdist(c(1,2,3), "normal")
Error in fitdist(c(1, 2, 3), "normal") : 
  The  dnormal  function must be defined

> fitdist(c(1,2,3), "norm")
Fitting of the distribution ' norm ' by maximum likelihood 
Parameters:
      estimate Std. Error
mean 2.0000000  0.4714045
sd   0.8164966  0.3333311
```

For reference, [here is a list of the distributions in the stats package](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.5.1/topics/Distributions).

Answer (score 0):

What is important to know, **the package [fitdistrplus](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fitdistrplus/vignettes/fitdistrplus_vignette.html) relies on loaded statistical functions as its backend**. For instance, I want to fit an inverse normal distribution and choose `SuppDists` out of its many implementations. Then I load `library(SuppDists)` first, and fit `fitdistrplus::fitdist` next. The full snippet:

```
install.packages("fitdistrplus")
install.packages("SuppDists")

library(fitdistrplus)
library(SuppDists)

# shelf-live data
X = c(24, 24, 26, 26, 32, 32, 33, 33, 33, 35, 41, 42, 43, 47, 48, 48, 48, 50, 52, 54, 55, 57, 57, 57, 57, 61)

fit <- fitdist(X, "invGauss", start = list( nu = 30, lambda = 10.5))
fit
# Parameters:
#         estimate Std. Error
# nu      42.88774    2.50325
# lambda 484.29802  134.32093
ks.test(x, (function (q) pinvGauss(q,nu=fit$estimate["nu"],lambda=fit$estimate["lambda"]) ), exact = TRUE )
# D = 0.17626, p-value = 0.3525
# alternative hypothesis: two-sided
```

reproduces the shelf-life data example from [The Inverse Gaussian Distribution and its Statistical Application-A Review](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2984691).